# "Can't compress a recycled bitmap" exception on single device

Tags: android, exception, bitmap, imageview

I am having a huge problem HTC Wildfire S device. My application starts second activity with image uri, user can rotate the image and then it's saved and returned to the main activity. The problem is on HTC only the first photo will be returned and the second will crash the application with the below error:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't compress a recycled bitmap
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkRecycled(Bitmap.java:372)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.java:799)
    at zapytaj.hot.or.not.ImageRotator.end(ImageRotator.java:151)
    at zapytaj.hot.or.not.ImageRotator$RotatorClass.onClick(ImageRotator.java:80)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9293)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

I have read that I should .copy bitmap to avoid this issue in another post, but couldn't figure it out, how to do it on my code. Thanks for your help. Code of the second activity included below:

```
package com.example.app;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ImageRotator extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "Rotator";
    private Uri file;
    private String suffix = "";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.picture);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

        file = getIntent().getData();
        suffix = b.getString("suffix");

        Bitmap bm = this.getBitmap();


        ImageView box = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        box.setImageBitmap(bm);

        ImageButton v1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.rotateLeft);
        ImageButton v2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.rotateRight);
        ImageButton v3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.save);
        v1.setOnClickListener(new RotatorClass());
        v2.setOnClickListener(new RotatorClass());
        v3.setOnClickListener(new RotatorClass());
    }


    class RotatorClass implements ImageButton.OnClickListener
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int id = v.getId();

            int change = 0;

            switch(id) {
                case R.id.rotateLeft:
                    change = -90;
                    break;
                case R.id.rotateRight:
                    change = 90;
                    break;
                case R.id.save:
                    end(true);
                    return;
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "change: "+change);

            ImageRotator.this.rotate(change);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {   
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Podane zdjęcie nie zostanie dodane. Kontynuować?");
        alertDialog.setButton("Tak", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  end(false);
              }
        });

        alertDialog.setButton2("Nie", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                alertDialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    public void rotate(int change) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        Bitmap bm = drawable.getBitmap();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(change);

        Bitmap bm2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        bm = null;

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bm2);      
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    public void end(boolean save) {

        Intent in = new Intent();

        if(save == true) {

            File file2 = new File(getRealPathFromURI(file));

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file2);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bm = drawable.getBitmap();

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, baos);
                byte[] b = baos.toByteArray(); 

                String base = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.NO_WRAP);

                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();

                bm.recycle();
                bm = null;

                in.setData(file);

                in.putExtra("base", base);
                System.gc();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        setResult(4,in);
        finish();
    }


    private Bitmap getBitmap() {

        Uri uri = this.file;
        InputStream in = null;

        ContentResolver mContentResolver = getContentResolver();

        try {
            final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 300000;
            in = mContentResolver.openInputStream(uri);

            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);
            in.close();

            int scale = 1;
            while ((o.outWidth * o.outHeight) * (1 / Math.pow(scale, 2)) > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
                scale++;
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "scale = " + scale + ", orig-width: " + o.outWidth       + ", orig-height: " + o.outHeight);

            Bitmap b = null;
            in = mContentResolver.openInputStream(uri);
            if (scale > 1) {
                scale--;
                // scale to max possible inSampleSize that still yields an image
                // larger than target
                o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inSampleSize = scale;
                b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);

                // resize to desired dimensions
                int height = b.getHeight();
                int width = b.getWidth();
                Log.d(TAG, "1th scale operation dimenions - width: " + width    + ", height: " + height);

                double y = Math.sqrt(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE
                        / (((double) width) / height));
                double x = (y / height) * width;

                Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) x,     (int) y, true);
                b.recycle();
                b = null;

                b = scaledBitmap;
            } else {
                b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            }
            in.close();
            return b;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(),e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

just use the copy facility of the original bitmap.

`Bitmap bm = drawable.getBitmap().copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false);`

`Config` - an enumerator with two or three optional values, to support the pixcel representation.

The boolean argument states if the result bitmap allows access to edit it's bits.